# Binary Bomb Phase 4, Stepping into func4 call

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

So I'm having some trouble with this assembly code and finding out what two digits are the answers. All I know is the input is supposed to be two digits separated by a space and based off the last comparison the last digit should equal 0x6b which is 107 in decimal. Func4 does something to the eax value to make it 107 but I'm not really sure. So what two numbers will be taken as input?. Any help would be appreciated.

```
0x000000000040135a <+0>:    sub    $0x18,%rsp
0x000000000040135e <+4>:    lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000401363 <+9>:    lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
0x0000000000401368 <+14>:   mov    $0x402e78,%esi
0x000000000040136d <+19>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000401372 <+24>:   callq  0x400d60 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x0000000000401377 <+29>:   cmp    $0x2,%eax
0x000000000040137a <+32>:   jne    0x40138a <phase_4+48>
0x000000000040137c <+34>:   mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
0x0000000000401380 <+38>:   cmp    $0x13,%eax
0x0000000000401383 <+41>:   jle    0x40138a <phase_4+48>
0x0000000000401385 <+43>:   cmp    $0x23,%eax
0x0000000000401388 <+46>:   jle    0x401395 <phase_4+59>
0x000000000040138a <+48>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040138f <+53>:   callq  *0x20340b(%rip)  <explode_bomb>
0x0000000000401395 <+59>:   mov    $0x23,%edx
0x000000000040139a <+64>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
0x000000000040139f <+69>:   mov    0xc(%rsp),%edi
0x00000000004013a3 <+73>:   callq  0x4010bc <func4>
0x00000000004013a8 <+78>:   cmp    $0x6b,%eax
0x00000000004013ab <+81>:   jne    0x4013b4 <phase_4+90>
0x00000000004013ad <+83>:   cmpl   $0x6b,0x8(%rsp)
0x00000000004013b2 <+88>:   je     0x4013bf <phase_4+101>
0x00000000004013b4 <+90>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00000000004013b9 <+95>:   callq  *0x2033e1(%rip)       <explode_bomb>
0x00000000004013bf <+101>:  add    $0x18,%rsp
0x00000000004013c3 <+105>:  retq
```

step into func4

```
 0x00000000004010bc <+0>:   push   %rbx
 0x00000000004010bd <+1>:   mov    %edx,%eax
 0x00000000004010bf <+3>:   sub    %esi,%eax
 0x00000000004010c1 <+5>:   mov    %eax,%ebx
 0x00000000004010c3 <+7>:   shr    $0x1f,%ebx
 0x00000000004010c6 <+10>:  lea    (%rbx,%rax,1),%eax
 0x00000000004010c9 <+13>:  sar    %eax
 0x00000000004010cb <+15>:  lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ebx
 0x00000000004010ce <+18>:  cmp    %edi,%ebx
 0x00000000004010d0 <+20>:  jle    0x4010de <func4+34>
 0x00000000004010d2 <+22>:  lea    -0x1(%rbx),%edx
 0x00000000004010d5 <+25>:  callq  0x4010bc <func4>
 0x00000000004010da <+30>:  add    %eax,%ebx
 0x00000000004010dc <+32>:  jmp    0x4010ec <func4+48>
 0x00000000004010de <+34>:  cmp    %edi,%ebx
 0x00000000004010e0 <+36>:  jge    0x4010ec <func4+48>
 0x00000000004010e2 <+38>:  lea    0x1(%rbx),%esi
 0x00000000004010e5 <+41>:  callq  0x4010bc <func4>
 0x00000000004010ea <+46>:  add    %eax,%ebx
 0x00000000004010ec <+48>:  mov    %ebx,%eax
 0x00000000004010ee <+50>:  pop    %rbx
 0x00000000004010ef <+51>:  retq
```

Comment: Why don't you use gdb to step through the assembly instructions? Use the gdb tui mode and registers views to help look into the registers while stepping through the assembly instructions.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: @AmeyaVS, I have tried numerous times but just can't see what happens with the value in %eax inside func4.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I'm trying to figure out the two numbers that are taken as input.

Comment: Is there any line in the assembly code that you don't understand 100%? We may be able to point you to the appropriate section of CSAPP or a manual.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I just figured it out! How do I close this case now? I'm not too familiar with this.

Comment: You can either answer the question in the `Your Answer` section if you think it will help future readers who have the same problem, or you can click on the `Delete` link under the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this is 33 107. Based off the last comparison statement in the main code we can see that the second number has to be equivalent to 0x6b which is 107 in decimal else it will explode. To get the first number I simply examined the dump code for func4 and saw that it was going through a binary search. Since we know from the main code that the value of the first number has to be between 19 and 35 based off the two comparisons, we can pick 27 as our first guess and see that the number needs to be higher than 27. Going through the registers at different stages throughout the code helped!